# How does the MATLAB symvar function work?

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

I read the documentation and help about the `symvar` function but I'm still confused about how it works, especially for the following example:

```
syms x y a
symvar(x + y, 1)
```

When I run this M-file, I get the answer `'x'`. Why am I getting this answer? Why not `'y'`? And what is the role of the number `1` written as the second argument?

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing you typed `help symvar` into the MATLAB Command Window, which is normally the best first step, but in this case you may have come across a small pitfall. This is because `symvar` is an [overloaded function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/overloading-functions-for-your-class.html): there is more than one copy, and the copy that gets called depends on the data type/class of the variables/objects that are passed to it. You can see all the versions by using the [`which`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/which.html) function with the `-all` option. The output I get on R2018a is:

```
>> which symvar -all
C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2018a\toolbox\matlab\funfun\symvar.m
C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2018a\toolbox\curvefit\curvefit\@fittype\symvar.m  % fittype method
C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2018a\toolbox\symbolic\symbolic\@sym\symvar.m      % sym method
C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2018a\toolbox\matlab\funfun\@inline\symvar.m       % inline method
```

Notice how there is a default version in `...\matlab\funfun`, and then three more versions for `fittype`, `sym`, and `inline` objects. When you type `help symvar` you get the help for the first one, which isn't very helpful because you want the help for the overloaded `sym` method. To get this, you should type `help sym/symvar`, and you'll see something like this:

```
 symvar Finds the symbolic variables in a symbolic expression or matrix.
     symvar(S), where S is a scalar or matrix sym, returns a vector sym
     containing all of the symbolic variables appearing in S. The
     variables are returned in lexicographical order. If no symbolic variables
     are found, symvar returns the empty vector.
     The constants pi, i and j are not considered variables.

     symvar(S,N) returns the N symbolic variables closest to 'x' or 'X'.
     If N exceeds the number of variables appearing in S, or equals inf,
     then all variables appearing in S are returned.
     Upper-case variables are returned ahead of lower-case variables.
     If S is a symbolic function the inputs to S are listed in front of the
     other free variables. 

     Examples:
        syms alpha a b x1 y

        symvar(alpha+a+b) returns
         [a, alpha, b]

        symvar(cos(alpha)*b*x1 + 14*y,2) returns
         [x1, y]

        symvar(y*(4+3*i) + 6*j) returns
         y
```

You can also use the online documentation for the newest MATLAB version: [`symvar`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/symvar.html)

These make it clear what `symvar` does for symbolic variables. It will return a vector of all symbolic variables it finds in the expression you pass it as the first argument. If you specify a second argument as a number, it will only return up to that many symbolic variables, choosing first the ones that are alphabetically closest to `'x'`.